# Node js path binary tree

Tags: javascript, search, tree

how to return to a binary tree multiple nodes  in a array or
a set
simple solution

Comment: Why do you expect only two paths, when three inputs are given?

Comment: Sorry my bad i should cooment this. If a path is contained within another then it should be excluded from the returned list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code:

- It expects internal nodes to have exactly two children. You should make use of the method `getNumberOfChildren`
- `path` shouldn't be a global variable, as that will pollute any further call of `getPaths`. I would suggest to use a *generator function*, so that the caller can take care of putting the results in their own array variable.
- Obviously `root.getValue() === pathsToFind`  is never going to be true as `pathsToFind` is an array, and the root's value is an integer. You can use `includes`, but that will bring a bad time complexity when the array is long. So I'd suggest to turn that array into a Set.

It wasn't explained in the question, but it seems like you don't want to include a path to a node, when that node is on a path to another node that needs to be included. In other words, when the array of values has pairs where one is the ancestor of the other, the ancestor can be ignored.

Here is how I would suggest to implement it (with generator):

```js
function* generatePaths(root, targetSet) {
    if (!root) return;
    const val = root.getValue();
    let foundPathsWithThisValue = false;
    for (let child = 0; child < root.getNumberOfChildren(); child++) {
        for (const path of generatePaths(root.getChild(child), targetSet)) {
            path.push(val);
            yield path;
            foundPathsWithThisValue = true;
        }
    }
    if (!foundPathsWithThisValue && targetSet.has(val)) {
        yield [val];
    }
}

function getPaths(root, targetValues) {
    return Array.from(generatePaths(root, new Set(targetValues)), path =>
        path.reverse().join("->")
    );
}

// No change below

class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.children = [];
    }

    addChild(node) {
        this.children.push(node);
    }

    getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    getChild(i) {
        return this.children[i];
    }

    getNumberOfChildren() {
        return this.children.length;
    }

    print(indent = 0) {
        console.log("-".repeat(indent), this.value);
        for (const child of this.children) {
            child.print(indent + 4);
        }
    }
}

const root = new Node(0);
const leftRoot = new Node(10);
const rightRoot = new Node(500);
root.addChild(leftRoot);
root.addChild(rightRoot);
const leftChild = new Node(150);
const rightChild = new Node(250);
leftRoot.addChild(leftChild);
leftRoot.addChild(rightChild);
const leftleftChild = new Node(200);
leftChild.addChild(leftleftChild);
const rightrightChild = new Node(300);
rightChild.addChild(rightrightChild);

// will output [ '0 -> 10 -> 150 -> 200', '0 -> 500' ]
console.log(getPaths(root, [150, 200, 500]));
```

Comment: Is there a chance to make this run in O(n)?

Comment: What is `n` in your view? There are several metrics at play here: the number of nodes in the tree; the number of values in the array (parameter), the number of nodes on the paths that are returned,...etc. If you pass as argument the values of all the leaves in the tree, then all possible root-to-leaf paths have to be returned, so that will in general be more than O(n) entries, and could easily be O(nlogn) entries, and in very unbalanced trees, it could be O(n²). So the time complexity will be at least that.

Comment: Is possible to solve this problem with recursive?

Comment: It already is recursive. `generatePaths` calls itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are free to use your accessors instead of root.children. But I guess it is clearer like this, at least for the answer.

Be careful, your property 'root' has the same name as the global variable root

```
function getPaths(root, pathsToFind) {
  let match = false;
  if (root === null) return [];
  if (pathsToFind.includes(root.getValue())) {
    match = true;
  }

  const pathChildren = root.children.map(child => getPaths(child, pathsToFind))
                      .filter(child => child.length > 0)
                      .map(value => `${root.getValue()} -- ${value}`);
  if (pathChildren.length > 0) {
    return pathChildren
  } else {
    return match ? [`${root.getValue()}`] : []
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to skip paths when the target is not a leaf node. I don't think that is how the asker intended it. `getPaths(root, [150])` should still return a path.

Comment: Yes i noticed that too.

Comment: Oh you are right.
Let's fix this